# Filter MYSQL price - I have error with 'IF'

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I have in databse 2 type variable: text and decimal(20,2) (I am writing a web application, and I would be confined to these two types of data as text and numeric to facilitate the operator to base).
In numeric data type I have sometimes all column, where is only the integer part, and when I result data, I have '32324244.00'. I would like remove this '.00'.

I wrote the code that checks whether an entry in the column > '.00'

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(`code`)>0,1,0) 
FROM `table_1` 
WHERE  substring_index(`code`,'.',-1) >=1 
AND  substring_index(`code`,'.',-1) <= 99
```

When is any record, code return '1', if not, '0';

I would like to develop this code and convert the numbers to do immediately in MySQL. So how is a '1 'to display the number of normal, as is '0' to do 'substring_index (`code`,'. ', 1)'

I have code:

```
SELECT IF(
 (SELECT IF(COUNT(`kod`)>0,1,0) FROM `table_1` 
  WHERE  substring_index(`kod`,'.',-1) >=1 
  AND substring_index(`kod`,'.',-1) <= 99)='1',`kod`,substring_index(`kod`,'.',1)
) WHERE `table_1`
```

This code not work, PhpMyAdmin return error:

> `#1064` - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `table_1`   LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Where is problem?

Sorry for my english :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, you didn't make your `WHERE` clause, and you didn't select from the table like that:

```
WHERE column = something
```

Try this instead:

```
select count(kod) 
from
( 
   SELECT IF(COUNT(`kod`) > 0, 1, 0) 
   FROM `table_1` 
   WHERE substring_index(`kod`, '.', -1) >= 1  
     AND substring_index(`kod`, '.', -1) <= 99) = '1', 
         `kod`, 
         substring_index(`kod`, '.', 1)
) t  .
```

If you have something with where clause, you can add it in the end; `WHERE table_1 = ....`  or something like that.

---

**Edit:**

```
SELECT IF((SELECT COUNT('kod') 
           FROM `table_1` 
           WHERE substring_index('kod', '.', -1) >= 1 
             AND substring_index('kod', '.', -1) <= 99 
             AND COUNT('kod')
         ) > '0', 
         'kod', 
         substring_index('kod', '.', 1)) as myvalue 
from `table_1`
```

---

**EDIT2:**

Try this:

```
SELECT IF((SELECT COUNT(kod) 
           FROM `table_1` 
           WHERE substring_index(kod,'.',-1) >=1 
             AND substring_index(`kod`,'.',-1) <= 99 
           having COUNT(kod) > '0'),
          `kod`,
          substring_index(`kod`,'.',1)
         ) as myvalue 
from `table_1`
```

[**LOOK DEMO SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14240/12)

**Side note:** Make sure that you have the column called `kod`.

Comment: I modify my code: `SELECT IF((SELECT COUNT('kod') FROM 'table_1' WHERE  substring_index('kod','.',-1) >=1 AND  substring_index('kod','.',-1) <= 99) > '0','kod',substring_index('kod','.',1)) FROM 'table_1'` and this not resolve my problem... I don't know where is problem,because this code `SELECT substring_index('kod','.',1) FROM 'table_1'` work good.

Comment: PhpMyAdmin return: `myvalue
kod`

Comment: can u give sample code of your tables and the wished result ?

Comment: ok, i chnage ' to &#96; and the update code return good result but as one result: `myvalue
36977143`

Comment: `... as myvalue from 'table_1' group by myvalue` result: `ERROR #1056 - Can't group on 'myvalue'`

Comment: yes , sorry for that , what you want to be the result ? the wished result u want?

Comment: Ok, my code after simple change @echo_me ('where' to 'from') is working: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2eeb Change in data SQL one `.00` to `.01` Problem is in PhpMyAdmin

Comment: i would like write it like that `having COUNT(kod) > '0'` because in your first query u checked that this query is `>0`

Comment: here the working query and if dont want check that the count is >0 u can remove it  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14240/12

Comment: here u was checking that `COUNT(`kod`)>0` in your query

Comment: and if you want the order just add this `order by myvalue` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14240/13

Comment: if it solved your problem make sure to accept the answer as solved to help others

Comment: Sorry, I don't think. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
'name' 'price' 'currency' 'code (kod)'    
'WYCIERACZKI płaskie QAP PASSAT B5 FL 2001-2005' '35.00' 'PLN' '36977143.00'
'WYCIERACZKA EKOLOGICZNA 45x75 cm GUMA WYCIERACZKI' '75.00' 'PLN' '27429666.00'
'BOSCH opel WYCIERACZKI Vectra C Omega Signum RAV4' '66.99' 'PLN' '79166309.00'
'NAJLEPSZE Wycieraczki AERO PREMIUM 530 mm 35-71 cm' '10.90' 'PLN' 41394344.00'
'PŁASKIE WYCIERACZKI VW SHARAN GALAXY + TYŁ 3 szt.' '49.00' 'PLN' '53684409.00'
'SERWISOWE WYCIERACZKI PEUGEOT 307 od 10.2004' '38.99' 'PLN' '12379457.00'
'PŁASKIE WYCIERACZKI VALEO _______ HONDA CIVIC' '63.00 'PLN' 54651109.00'
```

Ok, the second and fourth column is as decimal(20,2). The fourth column is only 'integer' i wold like show:

```
'WYCIERACZKI płaskie QAP PASSAT B5 FL 2001-2005' '35.00' 'PLN' '36977143'
'WYCIERACZKA EKOLOGICZNA 45x75 cm GUMA WYCIERACZKI' '75.00' 'PLN' '27429666'
'BOSCH opel WYCIERACZKI Vectra C Omega Signum RAV4' '66.99' 'PLN' '79166309'
'NAJLEPSZE Wycieraczki AERO PREMIUM 530 mm 35-71 cm' '10.90' 'PLN' 41394344'
'PŁASKIE WYCIERACZKI VW SHARAN GALAXY + TYŁ 3 szt.' '49.00' 'PLN' '53684409'
'SERWISOWE WYCIERACZKI PEUGEOT 307 od 10.2004' '38.99' 'PLN' '12379457'
'PŁASKIE WYCIERACZKI VALEO _______ HONDA CIVIC' '63.00 'PLN' 54651109'
```

Becaeuse price have decimal, I would like show this normal